# Moment Timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

I had a few concerns about using moment timezone conversion. I was using moment to convert to New York time from UTC using utcOffset. But later switched it to moment-timezone. The current implementation is:

```
console.log(moment(pickedDate).tz("America/New_York").format(format1));
```

The above implementation works properly. But, I had some questions. Like,

- whether this method takes into consideration the daylight savings time. And in the docs, it says they do so thats one down.
- Another is that, since I use a datepicker, the `pickedDate` is in the user's timezone as described by the browser locale information.
- What if the user is in New York? Will any problems arise? Or will moment handle it?
- And also, is there any more efficient way than this? Because I read that using moment is slow and moment-timezone is even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using something else that moment. Moment is no longer in active development. [See this](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

I use [day.js](https://day.js.org/) myself, and I am very pleased.

Working with timezones and DST can be very cumbersome. I don't think anyone can answer your question perfectly here.

Consider the using the following approaches:

- Make sure to always store date and time in the same timezone, and with no daylight saving information (like UTC)
- Only convert to the desired timezone/DST on the client-side
- Convert all dates and times back to UTC before sending to the server. (or make sure to define the timezone, and make sure the server can handle and convert back to UTC)